# Why does this design look so bad?

Tags: gui-design, android, guidelines

I am attempting to create a UI for my android app, my only real experience with UI in the past is web based.

Everything i try, seems to just look terrible as an app UI. Can anybody point me towards what i have done wrong?

**Add Client**
[image: Add Client Window]

**Add Exercise**
[image: Add Exercise Part 1]
[image: Add Exercise Part 2]

Comment: This question is open-ended enough that I'd think it should maybe be asked in chat instead of as a question....

Comment: I completely disagree, @BalinKingOfMoria. The fact he's feeling the issues indicates the OP has some sense of what works and what doesn't. Those without this innate sense are very difficult to assist. You can't see what you can't see. This guy feels the problem, he just needs a little help to see the solutions. His wording shows all the signs he'll be able to self educate from this innate point of recognition once armed with a design lexicon.

Comment: @bizzehdee Does it? To whom?? and bad, compared to what??

Comment: @bizzehdee  You're missing a sense of visual design. Read on visual design and how people perceive things. The Answer of this question could be  very broad or subjective. Move it to chat, if that works!

Comment: @HarshitChoudhary he doesn't need to read about how people perceive things. He's one of those rare people that are instinctively and innately correct in their assessment of their own production. That's not only rare, it's the first step to learning what constitutes good design. He just needs to build up a visual vernacular and lexicon, and trust his instincts.

Comment: @HarshitChoudhary I dare say, if you had this talent (and it is a talent), you'd recognise someone else expressing it in any of its forms, from latent (as we're seeing here) through to guru. Darren, I have complete faith that once you begin to recognise your own innate abilities to see the difference between crap designs and great designs, you'll grasp the finer meanings of Steve Job's most famous quote: "good artists copy, great artists steal", a quote he stole. Just find what you like and plagiarise the great ideas you see, then work on your balance and contrast in hierarchical weightings.

Comment: Bizzehdee,  read if you're really interested to know/learn.
@Confused Upvoted for unbiased suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

It looks 'off' to you because there's not enough contrast between weights of space, size, colour, saturation and shape.

It is juxtaposition in weightings of these attributes that gives the required hierarchy needed to be both visually appealing and functionally informative to the viewer. The initial "look" gathers up and processes and prioritises what to focus on, in an initial glance before any fixation occurs.

This gaze, upon a good design, provides suggested locations to choose from for saccades and fixations. The art is in matching both the target audience's expectations and the design's objective in a way that's enjoyable and effective, engaging and enlightening.

Head over to pinterest or dribbble and analyse what looks and feels right in the context of the above consideration of weightings in the properties mentioned.